# Выборка.Следующий() - ложь. Не работает выборка

Tags: 1с

Опять проблема с 1с. Работаю с регистром накопления. Написала следующий запрос и цикл к нему, в отладчике ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() - ложь, РезультатЗапроса выдает колонки и свойства их содержимого, но значение не показывает, а РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать() - ошибки в значении. Параметры вроде те, выборка должна быть непустой. Почему так происходит - ума не приложу, только учусь. Буду очень благодарна за помощь!

```
    Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст = 
"ВЫБРАТЬ
|  СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки.Номенклатура,
|  СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки.СуммаОстаток как Сумма,
|  СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки.КоличествоОстаток как Количество
|  ИЗ
|   РегистрНакопления.СебестоимостьТоваров.Остатки (
|  &МоментВремени,
|  Номенклатура В
|  ( ВЫБРАТЬ ОказаниеУслугиМатериалы.Материал
| ИЗ Документ.ОказаниеУслуги.Материалы как ОказаниеУслугиМатериалы
| ГДЕ  ОказаниеУслугиМатериалы.Ссылка =&Ссылка ))
| КАК СебестоимостьТоваровОстатки";
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("МоментВремени",МоментВремени());
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Ссылка", Ссылка);

РезультатЗапроса  = Запрос.Выполнить();
СуммаСебестоимости = 0;
ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();


Пока ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() Цикл 
СебестоимостьЕдиницы = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Сумма / ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Количество;
Движение = Движения.СебестоимостьТоваров.Добавить();
Движение.ВидДвижения = ВидДвиженияНакопления.Расход;
Движение.Период = Дата;
Движение.Номенклатура = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Номенклатура;
ТекСтр = Материалы.Найти(ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Номенклатура, "Материал");
Движение.Количество = ТекСтр.Количество;
Движение.Сумма = СебестоимостьЕдиницы * ТекСтр.Количество;
СуммаСебестоимости = СуммаСебестоимости + СебестоимостьЕдиницы*ТекСтр.Количество;
КонецЦикла;
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь консолью запросов для отладки запроса. Скорее всего что то с параметрами.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в строке `Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("МоментВремени",МоментВремени());`

МоментВремени() - *это момент непосредственно ПЕРЕД позицией документа, а если необходимо получить момент непосредственно после позиции документа, то используйте объект Граница*

```
// МоментСразуПослеДокумента = Новый Граница(ДокументСсылка,ВидГраницы.Включая);
ТекДокумент = Ссылка;
Момент = Новый МоментВремени(ТекДокумент.Дата, ТекДокумент.Ссылка);
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("МоментВремени", Момент );
```